# Laptop restarts when waking from sleep

Tags: suspend

I just started having this issue today.

I have my settings to suspend when the lid is closed. Using Ubuntu 16.04.
The laptop restarts every time I close my lid.

Any thoughts as to how I can fix this?

Edit: Suspend is not working as well. The laptop restarts when I use suspend. The laptop restarts when i try to wake it.

Comment: Is suspend working otherwise?

Comment: No, just checked - suspend isn't working as well.

Comment: Just to clarify: Does the laptop restart instead of going into suspend mode, or does it restart when you try to wake it?

Comment: @NickWeinberg It restarts when I try to wake it.

Comment: ok - I updated my kernel and everything works fine now!